# Reshaping images for input into Keras TimeDistributed function

Tags: python, image, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I've got a set of images that I would like to analyse in sequence. My training data have the shape (354, 260, 260, 1) - there are 354 images, each of the dimension (260,260,1). My intent is to build a CNN model that counts the number of objects in each image, but as the images are in sequence, I'm trying to include LSTM layers on top of that as well and that's where I ran into issues with the input dimensions. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a solution on this site or on google.

I've set up my model like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
            input_shape=(5,260,260,1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(5))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

I've specified `input_shape` as (5, 260,260,1) as I'd like the model to take into account 5 images in the past while making predictions on the current image (I hope my understanding of this is correct, please correct me if I'm wrong).

The above model gave the following summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
time_distributed_61 (TimeDis (None, 5, 258, 258, 16)   160       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_62 (TimeDis (None, 5, 129, 129, 16)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_63 (TimeDis (None, 5, 266256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_17 (LSTM)               (None, 5, 5)              5325240   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_33 (Dense)             (None, 5, 16)             96        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_34 (Dense)             (None, 5, 1)              17        
=================================================================
Total params: 5,325,513
Trainable params: 5,325,513
Non-trainable params: 0
```

When I compile the model, however, I run into this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-79-8e37c915d926> in <module>()
      1 model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
----> 2 history = model.fit(xtrain_rs, ytrain, validation_data=(xtest_rs, ytest),epochs=50,batch_size=32,verbose=1)

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    129                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    130                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 131                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    132                 if not check_batch_axis:
    133                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_61_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (354, 260, 260, 1)
```

I'm currently stuck here..not sure how I should reshape my training data to have 5 dimensions, or if I've made a mistake elsewhere? Would really appreciate any help!

**EDIT: solved** if anyone else has the same problem:
Batching has to be done using [TimeseriesGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/), before `Keras` can infer the batch size:

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
train_sequences = TimeseriesGenerator(xtrain_rs, ytrain, length=5, batch_size=64)
test_sequences = TimeseriesGenerator(xtest_rs, ytest, length=5, batch_size=64)

# fit model using fit_generator instead of fit
fit_generator(train_sequences,validation_data = test_sequences,epochs=10)

# sanity check
batch_x, batch_y = test_sequences[0]
batch_x.shape
```

The output shape from above is (64, 5, 260, 260, 1). My model above is now running.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are passing your whole dataset to the model,
you have to fetch from your dataset a batch of 5 images, in this case, you should set your input_shape=(260,260,1) and when you fit your model , pass the arguments as follow `model.fit(x_train, y_train,epochs=20,batch_size=5)`, but to do this, you have to prepare your data to be able to pop up 5 images by batch, here is a [link](https://keras.io/examples/cifar10_cnn/) on how to do batching and [another](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/) on how TimeDistributed works

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I'm still a little confused - doesn't the `batch_size` argument in `model.fit` refer to the minibatch size for each iteration of SGD, not the timestep? To fetch 5 images at a time from my dataset, I should be reshaping it to (samples, 5, rows, cols, channels)?

Comment: Keras infer the batch size, the network should be aware of the batch size, yes, that argument is the one that tells how many I mages it has to use on one pass, that why it is defined in the compiling argument but not in the network architecture.,